# Listview in Android Adds Extra Space to Top and Bottom of Some Rows

Tags: android, android-layout

One of my app's screens displays a listview with 6 columns, the sixth one being an imageView that contains a user-created picture or sketch. Here is the code for the listView row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/surveyColumn1"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.105"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/surveyColumn2"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.137"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/surveyColumn3"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/surveyColumn4"
       android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.153"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/surveyColumn5"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.153"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/surveyColumn6"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.202"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pictureHeader"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This setup works great except for one case: where the image being displayed is a vertically oriented picture taken by the camera. In that case the listview throws a bunch of blank space above and below the image inside the row. In the activity I'm using a custumViewBinder to display the image as a bitmap using code I got from here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

The only way I've found to get rid of the space is to set a static height to the imageView, which I'd rather not do since some rows won't have images. Anyone who can figure out what is happening is my hero.

Edit: Here is the class that I call to display the image as a bitmap:

```
public class customBitmap {

    public customBitmap(String pathName, int width, int height, ImageView view) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

        //Check if bitmap was created; if so, display it in the imageView
        if(bitmap == null)
            Log.w("UI Thread", "Null bitmap at moto.sitesurvey.customBitmap:35");
        else
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if(height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if(width > height)
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
            else
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

}
```

In the activity I am passing values of 200 and 150 for width and height. My problem seems to be that when I initially wrote this code a few months ago I only designed it to work for landscape-oriented pictures and now it needs to work for portrait as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the suggestion of stoney80 in my [post](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/17vna8/i_posted_a_question_in_stackoverflow_that_hasnt/) on r/androiddev, I added the line

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to the imageVew, and this got it to do exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you resizing the images before placing them in the view? If so, check and see what is the optimal size that images work with and try resizing the bitmaps taken from the vertically oriented camera to this size.

If this doesn't help you, I can look at your imageview and bitmap code?

Comment: I am resizing them (see newly attached code), and I guess I found 200 and 150 to work well for width and height, at least for landscape pictures. How would I test for a vertical camera shot?